# Drop down selection in ASP.Net MVC 3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am new to asp.net MVC 3. I want to create dropdown for each year, month and day. I created a helper class that collects common function. See below.

Common

```
Public Shared Function GetYearsList() As List(Of SelectListItem)

    Dim items As New List(Of SelectListItem)

    For i = -1 To 2500
        Dim item As New SelectListItem

        item.Text = Now.AddYears(i).Year.ToString()
        item.Value = Now.AddYears(i).Year.ToString()

        If i = Now.Year Then
            item.Selected = True
        End If

        items.Add(item)
    Next

    Return items

End Function
```

In the Controller class.

```
Function Index() As ActionResult

    ViewData("Year") = Command.GetYearsList()
    ViewData("Month") = Command.GetMonthsList()
    ViewData("Day") = Command.GetDaysList()

    Return View()

End Function
```

In the View page.

```
@Html.DropDownList("Year", DirectCast(ViewData("Year"), List(Of SelectListItem)), New With {.onchange = "setDate();"})
```

But it didnot select current year. How can I do to select current year. Otherwise has other solution for that? Thanks all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I show what you want but in C#. I think you can easily rewrite it to VB.

Firs of all, make a view model class for the view.

```
public class SomeViewModel
{
    public SomeViewModel()
    {
        this.Years = new List<int>();

        for (int i = -1; i <= 2500; i++)
        {
            this.Years.Add(DateTime.Now.AddYears(i).Year);
        }

        this.SelectedYear = DateTime.Now.Year;
    }

    public int SelectedYear { set; get; }
    public List<int> Years { set; get; }
}
```

It has a property that contains the years, and another for the selected one.

Second, make a simple controller method:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = new SomeViewModel();

    return View(model);
}
```

After this, make your strongly typed view:

```
@model YourAppNameSpace.ViewModels.SomeViewModel

...

@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedYear, new SelectList(Model.Years))
```

It will make a DropDownList containing the years, and the selected year is the current year.

Comment: I don't want to create a new class for year. It came from a common helper class. So, How can I do that?

Comment: It's not for year. It's a view model for the view. It should contain all the data that you want to display in the view. The years, months, etc.

Comment: For my case, the Birthday date property has in the view model. So, The year, month and day shouldn't include in the View model. For the postback, I created a hidden for birthday date. Then the three drop down value combine and post to server. So, the years, months and days data came from a common class and place a shared function. Thanks for your help.

Comment: If I understand correctly, I suggest you to use the jQuery ui's Date picker (http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) and have a DateTime Property in the view model.